Finding a subgroup of $G$, such a given set is a right coset.
I encountered this problem as an exercise, and I did not find a logical way to do it.
Finding a subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$, such that the set of matrices in $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ with determinant $−1$(denote as $B$)  is a right coset.
My try: Suppose we can find a subgroup $H$ and an element $A$, such that $HA=B$, then we need to satisfy every matrix in $H$ must have determinant -$\frac{1}{|A|}$. Additionally, $A$ must have determinant $-1$, so any element of $H$ should have determinant $1$. A rational choice will be the $SL_2(\Bbb{R})$. Miraculously, I choose $A$ to be $$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and it does satisfy.
However, it seems not a logical way since I guess the form of $A$ and $H$.
If I change the set $B$ as the set of matrices in $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ with top right entry $0$, I do not know how to 'Guess'.

If the set $B$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ then you can simply choose the subgroup to be $B$, because $B\cdot id$ is a right coset (as for the set of invertible matrices with top right entry $=0$). In the example with the determinant we are in the fortunate case that $det$ is a group homomorphism, i.e. $det^{-1}(1)$ is a subgroup and $det^{-1}(-1)$ is a coset (left and right coset are identical here, since kernels are normal). However, generally finding subgroups for general $B$ should be very hard.

If $S$ is a right coset of a group $G$, meaning that $S=Hz$ for some subgroup $H\le G$ and some element $z\in S$, then $H$ must equal the set $Sz^{-1} = \{ sz^{-1}\colon s\in S \}$. So there's only one possible choice for the subgroup $H$, which we can determine from any element $z\in S$. We just have to decide whether that set $H$ really is a subgroup of $G$ or not.

I do not understand why there is only one possible choice for the subgroup $H$. More specifically, why different $z$ determines the same $H$?

Because $Hz=Hz'$ implies there exist $h,h'\in H$ with $hz=h'z'$, and so $Hz = H(h^{-1}h'z') = (Hh^{-1}h')z' = Hz'$.

I am not sure what you proved here. It seems you start with $Hz=Hz'$ and end with $Hz=Hz'$

I think you are trying to say if $Hz=S$, then any element of $S$ can be expressed as $hz$, so $Hhz=S$
